# .Net MVC - Accessing the Database from within a View more than just Bad Practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've seen a few developers instantiate models that access the database from within a view. Typically they do this when they want to access an html partial and they just create a new viewmodel right there in the view :

```
<div class='blogListing'>
    @Html.Partial("BlogListing", new BlogListingViewModel(10));
</div>
```

To me, best practice would be to instantiate all of your models inside your ViewModels, then pass them to your partials. In the example below, BlogHomeViewModel would create a new BlogListingViewModel(10) and set it as a public property for the View to consume :

```
@Model BlogHomeViewModel

<div class='blogListing'>
    @Html.Partial("BlogListing", Model.BlogListing);
</div>
```

My question is, is this more than just a bad practice / maintenance issue? Are there also performance concerns for accessing a database from within a View? I would think a model would be able to fire off all of the database requests at about the same time, but within a View you're already starting to render html, and thus must open and close more connections,slowing down page load. Am I off-base here?

Answer (score 10):

As always, there's more than one way to skin a programmer.  That's how that saying goes, right?

Years ago when I first started using a MVC framework I kept trying to figure out what the gold standard was for what each letter should be responsible for.  There's a lot of opinions, but ultimately it's up to you and your team to figure out what works for you.

I would argue that connecting to the database within your view **or** model is bad practice.  Some people open connections within their models to pull in data.  Not me.  When I think about what a model is responsible for it's simply:

1. The data that will end up in display in the UI
2. The data that is needed to properly build the UI (e.g. a `bool` for conditionally showing some options)

I will often refer to my models as "self-sufficient".  What that means is my models need to have all the data required by the time it hits the view.  I let my controller handle database connections, API calls, LDAP queries and so on.  Obviously my controller doesn't contain all of the code for those methods (I have proper specialized libraries for handling different requirements), but, it is the broker between the different sources of data.

What's nice about architecting your applications in this fashion is that you are *certain* when your heavy lifting is done.  You know that when you call `return View(model)` that you have all the data that you need.  You don't have to troubleshoot bad queries (or slow API calls, etc) from your model or view.  Having that line drawn as to what each piece is responsible for is what makes the framework useful to me.

Remember, these are *my* opinions on how the framework should be used.  I'm not saying it's the only solution.  Your development team might find something more useful, but, keeping this discipline has been working well for me for a handful of years.

Comment: Nice - a well-reasoned, well-written, thoughtful answer.  For the first few MVC projects, I underestimated the value of maintaining the ViewModel discipline (here's everything you need to display the view).  There's a lot of value in that simplicity.

Comment: So your model is just a DTO with no processing and you fill the DTO in the controller itself?

Comment: I'm really asking more about performance considerations than about best practices. I think this could be concretely answered. Best practice opinions aside, is there a performance hit when creating multiple, database-accessing models from within a View?

Comment: @JPBerry - From a performance standpoint it doesn't matter where you perform your queries.  If you execute the same query in the controller versus the model, it's still one query and to the database it looks exactly the same.  If you're using an ORM like Entity Framework you always have to be careful if you a "feature" like lazy loading.

Comment: @Scottie - Yes and no.  I have DTO's that I pass to my controller from other libraries (like a third party API wrapper that I commonly use).  Using an example like that, I might take that list of objects (e.g. `List<User>`) and stuff that into my model.  I don't let my models make any connections to fetch data though; it's a one way road.

Answer (score 1):

The unwritten rule to not access the database from the view is not really about anything other than writing good maintainable code. Developers are always looking for some concrete validation for doing something: it's more performant, etc. Sometimes, you just do things because it won't make the developer that comes after you, well, want to come after you... with a butcher knife.

The whole purpose of MVC (the paradigm, in general) is separation of concerns and proper modularization of code. If you view needs to know how to access the database, you've broken the single-responsibility principle and tied your code in knots, where if database access changes, you need to change the view as well. That's not exactly common sense, so any developer unfamiliar with the codebase can (and Murphy says *definitely will*) come along and change something that affects that code in the view, without knowing that they affected the view, and your application goes down in flames.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there would be any performance issues from calling the DB from your view.  It all get processed in IIS anyways before it ever hits the browser.  The only exception would be if you are opening/closing connections multiple times.

Typically, the main reason to keep the seperation of concerns is so that each part of the M V C has a specific duty and you aren't looking all over to figure out just where this data came from.

Also, from a unit testing standpoint, you'd want to keep your data access in a place where it could be tested, and the view isn't a very good place for that.