# How do you pass a variable to @{ } to build a Query as only global variable is visible

Tags: asp.net-mvc, variables, scope

I cannot pass the variable the create for the table is below for testing database is KSI, using MS SQL EXPRESS. The OPen and query I believe used the Webmatrix calls

It does not matter what the statements do, it's about passing visibility of the variables.

This is just supposed to read `sdata` and pass it to `selcmd`.

Here is the problem with this code, the variable `selcmd` does not exist in this context.
`Global_selcmd` does but I am unable to pass `selcmd` to the code after the `@{` sign, only works with global variable.

> selcmd    error CS0103: The name 'selcmd' does not exist in the current context

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <form name="myForm" method="POST">
        Created by: <input type="text" name="sdata" style="width: 434px" 
    size="25"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>

    @{ 
    var db = Database.Open("KSI");
    // swap the following comment lines
    //var selcmd = "INSERT INTO [KSI].[dbo].[Proposal] ([ProposalNo],
                       [EntDate]) VALUES ('" + sdata + "', GETDATE() )";
    var selcmd = "INSERT INTO [KSI].[dbo].[Proposal] ([ProposalNo],
                  [EntDate]) VALUES ('" + "tst2text" + "', GETDATE() )";

    //alert("EXECUTING: b4 " + selcmd);
    db.Query(selcmd);
    //alert("DONE: " + selcmd);
}
```

Comment: Is this a Razor view?

Comment: Yes.  Should I be using something like: db.Execute("INSERT INTO proposal (ProposalNo) VALUES (@0)", sdata);
}

Comment: No. You [should not have](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20248494/11683) this kind of code in a view.

Comment: what if input in sdata is 1',1);DROP DATABASE KSI;-- spoiler: this would delete your whole database

Comment: true, but this is just a test way to get past my problem that I am unable to hand the result of after sdata is changed on the screen, to the sql statement.  I would use a SQL proc in production, db.Execute("DatainProc",sdata);  (I cant get this to work either, only can pass the original var @{var sdata = "12345abcd"; }